# Legend from raster not appearing correctly when uploaded to ArcGIS Online

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I am using ArcGIS Pro 3.1.0

I have a raster layer that I have uploaded as a tile service to my online project. I used the configuration when uploading like this:

[image]

The range looks like this in Pro, and I assumed that the color range would get copied into my project as well:

[image]

However, this is how it appears when added to ArcGIS Online map:

[image]

Is the tiling scheme wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now solved. I had transparency on my raster in ArcGIS Pro, and had to set this to zero to be able to see the legend in ArcGIS Online. The transparency can be set in ArcGIS Online, if that is needed.